# Cakephp file upload character corruption

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to use form to set a user data.
This is my code.It is garbled when enter the Japanese.
However, it works well when i exclude 'type' => 'file'.
Configuration and database is set to utf8 all.
Please give to advice.

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'userprofileedit',$user_id ),'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('upfile', array('label' => array('text' => 'upfile'),'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('nickname',array('label' => array('text' => 'nickname'),"value"=>$nickname));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Save'));
```

Comment: please put exact error here ...

Comment: Thank you for reply.This case does not have the error occurred.

Comment: array(
 'User' => array(
  'nickname' => 'ã¢ãã¡',
  'upfile' => array(
   'name' => '',
   'type' => '',
   'tmp_name' => '',
   'error' => (int) 4,
   'size' => (int) 0
  )
 )
)

Comment: This is Debugger::dump($this->request->data);Detail.

Comment: 'error' => (int) 4 -> no files uploaded. in which case u got this?

Comment: That’s right.if upload the file,error don't happen.

Comment: array(
 'User' => array(
  'nickname' => 'ãã¹ã',
  'upfile' => array(
   'name' => '3.jpg',
   'type' => 'image/jpeg',
   'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpPVgOvc',
   'error' => (int) 0,
   'size' => (int) 217196
  )
 )
)

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading a file for the User, replace the form creation:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'userprofileedit',$user_id ),
    'type' => 'file'
));
```

with:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    'url' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'userprofileedit',$user_id ),
));
```

Also make sure that your app/core.php has:

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I've tried, but the results did not change.

Comment: echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
            'url' => array('controller' => 'Services', 'action' => 'userprofileedit',$user_id )
           ));

Comment: only this case don't happen. But, can not upload file.

Comment: array(
 'User' => array(
  'nickname' => 'アニメ'
 )
)

Comment: Please show the code of your edit() method in the Controller and describe how you detect the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.Only Debugger.

Comment: Debugger::dump($this->request->data);

Comment: if the content of your fields gets "corrupted" going from the browser to your POST data, there's must be something wrong/missing in tyour form definition. I suggest to create a plain HTML file with the form code and test that with Firebug. I'm sorry I can't help more. Good luck

Comment: Today,I've solved this problem.
I changed to off the mbstring.encoding_translation of php.ini file.
This parameter will override the settings of the application side encoding.

Thank you everyone.